# ShallowCopy with MemoryStream class c#

Tags: c#, clone, shallow-copy

I have this generic methos for deep copy. I am worried if it may cause any issues? Is it 100% safe? If not, when can it fail and what I should watch out for?

```
/// <summary>
/// Makes a copy from the object.
/// Doesn't copy the reference memory, only data.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the return object.</typeparam>
/// <param name="item">Object to be copied.</param>
/// <returns>Returns the copied object.</returns>
public static T Clone<T>(this object item)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        formatter.Serialize(stream, item);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        T result = (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        stream.Close();

        return result;
    }
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

Example:

```
Customer customerCopy = customer.Clone<Customer>();
```

Comment: If the class/object is marked with the `Serializable` attribute this should work fine (as far as I know). I have never really heard of any serialization problems resulting in corrupt data or similar.

Comment: As far as for references: This creates a completely new object with new references. So yes, it's a deep copy.